# How to show hidden errors in console on chrome for javascript code?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm not able to see the errors during the debug of my app on chrome please help with settings.
[image]

Comment: Click `Default levels` and customize the dropdown selector.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you,an image would help

Comment: https://puu.sh/A6lgW/7bd53704b1.png

Comment: @wOxxOm tried still not showing errors...:(

Comment: Maybe you've checked "hide network errors" in devtools settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Solution :-**

*[See The Right Side Of Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xkyj.png)*

> **Explanation :-**

*You Will See A **Default Levels** Drop down List*
*Check The List Items According To Your Needs*

Comment: Mine are all checked but still not showing errors for some reason.

Answer (score 28):

Even after checking the '**Errors**' under '**Default**', I was not able to see the errors in the console.

I then navigated to settings (or press <kbd>F1</kbd>) and on the bottom of the page, you will see '**Restore defaults and reload**' option.

[image]

After restoring to defaults, I am able to see the console errors.

Comment: I tried a dozen other things and this is the first thing to work. I'm guessing a chrome upgrade screwed up some hidden settings

Answer (score 10):

I hope this helps someone. In my case, none of the above solutions helped. The culprit was the filter text field shown in the below image.

[image]

Clear the text field and the errors will be shown again.

Comment: Love it. This worked for me, and then I was able to re-hide them with right click on the console message.

Answer (score 4):

If none of these solutions work for you, remove the text in the "filter" box.

Comment: The obvious solution and one that I kept overlooking... thanks for putting this here.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure '**Selected context only**' option is deselected.

Chrome creates context not only for current page, but also for embedded iframes and browser extensions. This could narrow visibility of logs. This was the case for me.

[image: devtools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Verbose option in the Default levels dropdown menu.

Answer (score -1):

I had "18 hidden" in Chrome, but could not inspect what I at the time thought was errors. Turns out I simply had not checked all logging levels. You will of course get more hidden log-messages the fewer logging levels you have checked.

[image]

[image]